# Derivative of Integral with changing integrand and bounds of integration

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $F(s)= \int_0^{g(s)}f_s(t)dt$ where $g$ is a smooth function and $f_s$ is smooth family of functions. How to calculate the derivative $F'(s)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: To avoid closing, show some of your effort at solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under good conditions of smoothnes and integrability of $f(x,s) $ and its partial in $s$ we have the differentiability under the integral sign. The derivative of $F(s) $ is given by the Leibniz integral rule $$F'(s) =g'(s)f(g(s) ,s)+\int_0^{g(s)}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(x,s)dx.$$

Comment: could you share a reference? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Check this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjjx8Kv4Zr_AhVWTKQEHV79AmYQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2AAHzEEz_m8cDUpDDyWQ5B